# 'this' keyword in Java

Tags: java, oop, this

I have a question regarding `this` in the following code. In the following, `this.name`  will set the name. We could also do this using `name = name`, so my question is should the `this` pointer be used. This is not an homework

```
import java.io.*;

public class Employee{
    String name;
    int age;
    String designation;
    double salary;

    //This is the constructor of the class Employee
    public Employee(final String name){ //EDIT: Made parameter final
        this.name = name;
        //name= name; this is also correct
    }

    //Assign the age of the Employee  to the variable age.
    public void empAge(int empAge){
        age =  empAge;
    }

    //Assign the designation to the variable designation.
    public void empDesignation(String empDesig){
        designation = empDesig;
    }

    //Assign the salary to the variable salary.
    public void empSalary(double empSalary){
        salary = empSalary;
    }

    //Print the Employee details
    public void printEmployee(){
        System.out.println("Name:"+ name );
        System.out.println("Age:" + age );
        System.out.println("Designation:" + designation );
        System.out.println("Salary:" + salary);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the edit public Employee(final String name){ name =name }

Comment: I would perhaps make that clear as a separate successive edit, otherwise the answers you've already received won't make much sense in the new context

Comment: As a matter of style/convention, it's usual to give your getters and setters the form `public Type getVariable()` and `public void setVariable(Type variable)`. When you have an instance of this object `employee.setAge(21)` is more obvious than `employee.empAge(21)`

Comment: @BrianAgnew I've proposed an edit where an code comment `//EDIT: Made parameter final` is added on the appropriate line to try and clear this up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  //      name= name; this is also correct
```

This is *not* correct. It'll assign your parameter to itself. By using the `this` keyword, you're declaring *which* name you're using (i.e. the field on your `Employee` object).

You may wish to name the field differently from the parameter. However this means that all works well until someone automatically refactors your code to (perhaps inadvertently) declare the field and parameter as the same name!

For this reason you'll often see method signatures defined thus:

```
public Employee(final String name)
```

The `final` keyword prevents reassignment, and stops you from mistakenly reassigning the input parameter, and consequently not assigning to your field. Note also that if you declare the *field* as `final`, then compilation will fail if you don't make an assignment to that field. Using `final` is a good way to trap such errors and also enforce the *immutability* of an object (often a good thing - it contributes to a more reliable solution, especially in a threaded environment).

Comment: k even if we use public Employee(final String name) then we can write name =name .right?

Comment: I haven't tried it but I suspect not. I would make both the field and the parameter final, and then your options for making mistakes are massively reduced!

Comment: The advantage of declaring the parameter as `final` is that you at least get a compiler error when you try and do `name = name`. In order to refer to the member variable (The one defined by `String name;` in your class - you should probably add a `private` access level modifier to that too), you *must* use the `this` keyword when the parameter has the same name as the member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well to avoid the confusion in cases like u mentioned name=name we uses this pointer to make it clear the we here mean class variable name .

So to make understand the reader here in this case we use this though there can be many other cases where (this) is more useful.

In some compilers name=name gives error as well

Answer (score 1):

Notice that there are two things called `name` in your code. Your class `Employee` has member variable called `name`, and the constructor takes a parameter that's also called `name`.

What you want to do in the constructor is set the member variable `name` to the same value as the parameter `name`. To access the member variable, you have to use `this.name`, because `name` refers to the parameter - because the variables have the same name, the parameter is **hiding** the member variable.

Note that `name = name;` does not do the same thing as `this.name = name;`.

When you do `name = name;`, you assign the value of the parameter `name` to the parameter itself - **not** to the member variable. The compiler does not magically know that the first `name` is supposed to mean the member variable, and the second `name` is supposed to mean the parameter.

So, you need `this` in this case to refer explicitly to the member variable, instead of the parameter that is hiding the member variable.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `this` is just a scope resolution/disambiguation.

```
public Employee(String name){
  this.name = name;
  // the above line will assign a value of parameter to instance variable
  //      name= name; this is also correct
  // (**NO** the above line will assign a value of parameter to itself) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the parameter name and your class variable names are same, then to differentiate between them, you write `this.classVariable` to identify the class variale

Answer (score 1):

When you call a variable, the pointing one is the one who is the closest to your current scope.

So, if program is currently containing in memory a local variable `toto` and the wrapping class containing a field variable `toto`, you have to precise `this` keyword in order to access the field's one.

Otherwise, the field variable is said to be **shadowed** by the local variable and so doing `toto = toto` assigns the local parameter to itself (never useful) and not what you are expecting => the field variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so hard on yourself?

Just rewrite the signature/method like this:

```
public Employee(String _name) {
   name = _name;
}
```

Always try to avoid variable hiding or other hard-to-read constructs. If you want your code to be maintainable, write it in such a way that everybody can understand it immediately. Even if you are the only one; you might forget what you meant in time.

Answer (score -1):

> This Keyword Program
>
> public class ThisKeywordActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> int a=20;
>
> public ThisKeywordActivity(int a) { //        this();
>     //this.a = a;
>
> }
>
> public  ThisKeywordActivity()
> {
>     System.out.println(" msg default Constructor ");
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_this_keyword);
>
>
>     ThisKeywordActivity thisKeywordActivity2 = new ThisKeywordActivity(100);
>
>     thisKeywordActivity2.show(40);
>
> }
>
> public  void  show( int a)
> {
>     System.out.println("msg  a 2==="+a);
>     System.out.println("msg  a 3==="+this.a);
> }
> ```
>
> }

```
Output 

a2=40
a3=20
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is a random block of low-quality code with little relation to the question